# Что означает это выражение в си?

Tags: c, строки

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
static const char delims[] = "\t\n\r ";
int main()
{
    int SIZE=200;
    char s[SIZE];
    printf("Frase: ");
    char *res = fgets(s, SIZE, stdin);
    int a=0, b=0;
    puts(s);
    for (char *word = strtok(s, delims); word != NULL; word = strtok(NULL, delims)){
        for(int i=0; i<strlen(word); i++){
            if(word[i]==(toupper(word[i]))){
                a=1;
            }
            else{
                a=0;
                break;
            }
        }
        b=b+a;
    }
    printf("%d", b);
    return 0;
}
```

Вот это "static const char delims[] = "\t\n\r ";", что означает, это как бы знаки препинания, но не могу понять, как они так "вызываются".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Это неизменяемый, видимый только в данном файле массив из пяти символов — табуляции (`\t`), новой строки (`\n`), возврата каретки (`\r`), пробела ( ) и завершающего нулевого символа, используемый в функции `strtok` для указания разделителей слов.

Дополнительную информацию о такой записи символов — через `\` — можно найти в любом учебнике по С/С++.

```
Символ  Описание
\r      возврат каретки в начало строки
\n      новая строка
\t      горизонтальная табуляция
\v      вертикальная табуляция
\"      двойные кавычки
\'      апостроф
\\      обратный слеш
\0      нулевой символ
\?      знак вопроса
\a      сигнал бипера (спикера) компьютера
```